# Can't implement javascript flip counter in Rails project

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I have problems with implementing javacript flip counter in Rails project.

In plain html page everything is working fine, but I think I have some problems with asset-pipeline.

I added all needed files into assets directory. Images, javascripts, css files.

Here ar my included files:

```
  <link href="/assets/application.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="/assets/counter.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/assets/jquery-ui.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/assets/jquery-flipcounter.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/assets/application.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Here are what scripts should be inclunded( from demo ):

```
     <!-- My flip counter script, REQUIRED -->
     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/flipcounter.js"></script>
     <!-- Style sheet for the counter, REQUIRED -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/counter.css" />
```

HTML:

```
  <div id="counter" class="flip-counter"></div>
```

and code from application.js(**working in plain HTML file**):

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
   var myCounter = new flipCounter("counter", {inc: 1, pace: 500});
    ...});
```

and here is rar archive with working counter: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/86122402/cnanney-apple-style-flip-counter-13fd00129a41.rar.

What I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

**For rails 2.x.x**

Move your `js/flipcounter.js` to `public/javascript` folder and

1. write below line in your `application.html.erb` in your `layout folder` **or** In a view file that it require

**For rails 3.x.x**

Move your `js/flipcounter.js` to `assets/javascript` folder and define in your

If in your `application.js`

```
  //= require_tree .           # if present 
  //= require flipcounter.js   # if require_tree. not present
```

**Your problem in**

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/flipcounter.js"></script>
```